# Math steps to get to answer

Tags: transistors, bjt, math

I have a issue understanding the math steps used to simplify an equation after deriving it.

I would be grateful if someone would show all the steps taken to get from equation 1 to equation 2 shown below.

1.$$\frac{Io}{Iref} = \frac{(1 + \frac{2}{\beta})}{(1 +\frac{2}{\beta} + \frac{2}{\beta^2} )}$$
2.

$$\frac{Io}{Iref} = \frac{1}{(1 +\frac{2}{\beta^2 + 2\beta} )}$$

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a math question

Comment: Multiply numerator and denominator by \$\beta^2\$ and then do polynomial long division. See where that gets you.

Comment: @Eugene Sh It may be a math question, but it's related to electronics. I'm sure your familiar enough with electronics to know that understanding mathematics is a fundamental part of the science.

Comment: @David777 Doesn't mean it's an electronics question though. This equation was presented in a vacuum and the issue you have with it is not an electronics design problem. It's a math one.

Comment: @DKNguyen But what if an op has a maths issue that is with regards to an electronics design problem, is it not the same thing? Are you saying I should edit my question to provide more information about the design?

Comment: @David777 If it was part of a design that would be different, although in this case your question didn't even need any design information to be answered.

Comment: @DKNguyen It's ok, my question has been answered. You can vote to close the question now if you want. I'll use the maths stack forum from now on to save any hassle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from 1. $$\frac{\left(1 + \frac{2}{\beta}\right)}{\left(1 +\frac{2}{\beta} + \frac{2}{\beta^2}\right)}$$

Divide the top and bottom by \$\left(1+\frac{2}{\beta}\right)\$ to get

$$\frac{1}{\left(\frac{1+\frac{2}{\beta}}{1+\frac{2}{\beta}} + \frac{\frac{2}{\beta^2}}{1+\frac{2}{\beta}}\right)}$$

Then:

$$\frac{1}{\left(1 + \frac{2}{\beta^2(1+\frac{2}{\beta})}\right)}$$

Just expand the lower denominator to get:

2. $$\frac{1}{\left(1 +\frac{2}{\beta^2 + 2\beta}\right)}$$

Comment: Thanks for your great answer, I fully understand now.